# mysql join slow performance

Tags: mysql, join, relationship

i have 3 table with structures

```
plans
- id
- cost_center_code
- cost_element_code
- val_usd

commitments
- id
- cost_center_code
- cost_element_code
- val_usd

actuals
- id
- cost_center_code
- cost_element_code
- val_usd
```

i want join 3 table using 2 key (cost_center_code,cost_element_code) and show sum val_usd from each table

this my current query and took 15-20s

```
select 
    plans.cost_center_code,
    plans.cost_element_code,
    sum(plans.val_usd) as plan_usd,
    sum(commitments.val_usd) as commitment_usd,
    sum(actuals.val_usd) as actual_usd 
from `plans` 
    left join `commitments` 
        on 
            `plans`.`cost_center_code` = `commitments`.`cost_center_code` 
            and `plans`.`cost_element_code` = `commitments`.`cost_element_code` 
    left join `actuals` 
        on 
            `plans`.`cost_center_code` = `actuals`.`cost_center_code` 
            and `plans`.`cost_element_code` = `actuals`.`cost_element_code` 
    where 
        date(`plans`.`document_date`) = '2021-07-27' 
        and date(`commitments`.`document_date`) = '2021-07-27' 
        and date(`actuals`.`document_date`) = '2021-07-27' 
        and `plans`.`deleted_at` is null 
    group by `plans`.`cost_center_code`, `plans`.`cost_element_code` 
limit 10
```

[edit]

my query result

[image: query result]

`EXPLAIN` query result

[image: EXPLAIN query result]

Comment: Have you tried the EXPLAIN syntax? And are you using indeces?

Comment: Its useful to include `show create table commitments` for table structure. `EXPLAIN {query}` output will show the query execution which forms the basis of improving it. `date(...) = '2021...` is unnecessary as its already a date, or is it a datetime? (hence `show create table`). If you have `where` critiera on `commitments` and `actuals` then it isn't a `left join` any more.  Moving those criteria to the `join ... on` criteria will keep it being a left join (if there are no commitments/actuals for a cost center you want the result right).

Comment: cost_center_code and cost_element_code have index,i want show all plans with group by cost_center_code and cost_element_code

Comment: Why 3 separate tables?

Comment: Use `FORMAT(usd, 2)`, the output will be much nicer.

Comment: because the data comes from 3 excel files which is imported separately